# Select on the same column multiple times with a different threshold and then combine the results (in a Google Big Query View)

Tags: sql, join, select, google-bigquery

I have several threshold values in table X (.1, .2, .005).  In table Y I have a prediction score (e.g. .14).  I want to create a view in BigQuery that combines the results of querying table Y n times (n = number of entries in table X).  i.e. like a dynamic union. In Big Query the views cannot have variable declarations or scripting within.
**If I knew there were only three values I would just do something like this:**

```
Select COLUMNS, .01 as threshold from Y where prediction > .01
union all 
Select COLUMNS, .02 as threshold from Y where prediction > .02
union all
Select COLUMNS, .005 as threshold from Y where prediction > .005
```

Unfortunately, I need to be dynamic in which values I use as thresholds and do not know how many there are (thus table X). In this trivial example it is not obvious why, but I do need to create these three sets of rows. Because I'm also doing transformations based on the value of the column and threshold (and other variables not shown) so each does become row becomes unique in its values in columns not shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT y.*, x.threshold
FROM `project.dataset.tableY` y
JOIN `project.dataset.tableX` x
ON y.prediction > x.threshold
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tableX` AS (
  SELECT 0.01 AS threshold UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.02 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.005
), `project.dataset.tableY` AS (
  SELECT 0.014 prediction UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.023 UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.0051
)
SELECT y.*, x.threshold
FROM `project.dataset.tableY` y
JOIN `project.dataset.tableX` x
ON y.prediction > x.threshold
```

with output

```
Row prediction  threshold    
1   0.014       0.01     
2   0.014       0.005    
3   0.023       0.01     
4   0.023       0.02     
5   0.023       0.005    
6   0.0051      0.005
```